# fail updating data with same primay key

Tags: php, mysql

I have script `insert` and `update` data in 1 file. `insert` data is succeed but if i want `insert` same data it will create new row with same `USERID`

The primary key is `USERID`.
I have tried with data comparison but it didn't work.

here my script.

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE USERID='$USERID';")
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){ 
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
    if ((int)$row['USERID'] = (int)$USERID){ 
    $sql=("UPDATE DATA SET SANDI='$SANDI', Photo='$Photo', Name='$Name' WHERE USERID='$USERID';"); 
}
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: should be `if ((int)$row['USERID'] == (int)$USERID){ `

Comment: You have to read any tutorial about PHP and MySQL first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do a query first and then taken an action based on that result. Use the ON DUPLICATE option of the SQL INSERT statement which will either insert the row for you or update an existing row.

```
$sql= ("INSERT INTO DATA 
    SET USERID = '$USERID' ,
        SANDI  = '$SANDI'  , 
        Photo  = '$Photo'  , 
        Name   = '$Name'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        SANDI  = '$SANDI' , 
        Photo  = '$Photo' , 
        Name   = '$Name'");
```